# The proper way to filter a backbone.collection by using Marionette.CompositeView

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have a `Marionette.CompositeView` which needs to render a collection.
I would like to filter this collection on `fetch` and `add` action.
I tried with the following code (1) but I get the following error (2).

Any ideas, thanks.

---

(1)

```
var myCompositeView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({

    initialize: function () {
        this.collection = app.taskCollection.where({type: 'todo'});
    }

});
```

(2)

```
// Uncaught TypeError: Object  has no method 'on'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Marionette's CompositeView and CollectionView both expect the `collection` setting to be a valid Backbone.Collection. The `where` method on Backbone's collection does not return a Backbone.Collection, it return an array. So you have to wrap a collection around the results:

```
initialize: function(){
  var filtered = app.taskCollection.where({type: 'todo'});
  this.collection = new Backbone.Collection(filtered);
}
```

Of course you can use any type that extends from Backbone.Collection. I just wanted to illustrate the point of it being a collection with this example.

Comment: Somewhat unrelated but ... if you are using routes to pass in filter criteria, the collection won't necessarily be ready/fetched in order to be filtered by the time 'initialize' is called?